# I exported a runnable jar using eclipse of my javafx14 application but cannot run the application

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, fxml, executable-jar

I have a problem, I am currently working on a javafx14 project on eclipse, And the project is almost done.

So I exported the application as a runnable jar. But when I try to run it using console by typing.

```
java --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar app.jar
```

or

```
java -jar app.jar
```

or anything really.
It gives me the following

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found
```

or this :

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

Please Help. And thanks in advance

Comment: This suggests your %PATH_TO_FX% variable is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I verified and the variable is correct

Comment: You should probably post the contents of the folder that variable points to.

Comment: The folder contains three sub-Folder /bin/
 (on Windows this will contain some .dll files)
/legal/
 (contains licenses)
/lib/
 (this contains some .jar files)

Comment: The variable points to the lib sub-Folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by making sure to put the jar file in the same place as the library folder.

like this:

```
-Jar file.

-Folder: lib
```

So in summary just make sure the jar file is in the same place as your lib.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the full path to javafx controls. I recommend using gradle or maven as a picker. Using gradle, you can create a bat file that will run your app and take care of the rest.

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0smrp.png)

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.17.2'
}

javafx {
    version = "11.0.2"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls' ] // you can add 'javafx.fxml', ...
}

group 'flpe'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

// Use Java 13 only if you use Gradle 6+
// The JDK folder must be added to the environment variable JAVA_HOME 
 (https://www.wikihow.com/Set-Java-Home)
sourceCompatibility = 1.11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jlink {
    launcher {
        name = 'exe_name'
    }
}
mainClassName = 'javafx.jlink.example.main/gui.Main'
```

**modul-info.java** necessarily!

```
module javafx.jlink.example.main {
    requires javafx.controls;
    exports gui;
}
```

**Main.java**

```
package gui;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Useless button");

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```